# How do I access highlighting variables in this JSON(p) return using jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, jsonp

I have the following JSON(p) data feed:

```
{
 "responseHeader": {
"status": 0,
"QTime": 3,
"params": {
  "indent": "true",
  "q": "content_de:text",
  "_": "1380870078953",
  "hl.simple.pre": "",
  "hl.simple.post": "",
  "hl.fl": "title_de,content_de,url_de",
  "wt": "json",
  "hl": "true",
  "rows": "1"
}
},
"response": {
"numFound": 74,
"start": 0,
"docs": [
  {
    "id": "de.ard-text.www:http/",
    "boost": 1.0202688,
    "digest": "e336d1ab12763514d4e1a9323e9c55ac",
    "tstamp": "2013-12-30T15:54:02.417Z",
    "lang": "de",
    "content_de": [
      "ARD Text - Der Teletext im Ersten Nutzen Sie bitte zur bestmöglichen Audio-Ausgabe die Screenreader-optimierte Version unseres ARD-Textes.                                       "
    ],
    "title_de": [
      "ARD Text - Der Teletext im Ersten"
    ],
    "keywords_de": [
      "Nachrichten-Überblick, Sport Nachrichten, Wetter, Gewinnzahlen, Fernsehen Das Erste, Sport Bundesligen, Boulevard, A-Z"
    ],
    "description_de": [
      "ARD Text, der Teletext des Ersten, bietet rund um die Uhr Nachrichten, Sport- und Programminformationen - auch im Internet und mobil."
    ],
    "suggest_de": [
      "ARD Text - Der Teletext im Ersten Nutzen Sie bitte zur bestmöglichen Audio-Ausgabe die Screenreader-optimierte Version unseres ARD-Textes.                                       "
    ],
    "url_de": [
      "http://www.ard-text.de/"
    ],
    "_version_": 1447714629877760000
  }
]
},
  "highlighting": {
"de.ard-text.www:http/": {
  "title_de": [
    "ARD Text - Der Teletext im Ersten"
  ],
  "content_de": [
    "ARD Text - Der Teletext im Ersten Nutzen Sie bitte zur bestmöglichen Audio-Ausgabe die"
  ],
  "url_de": [
    "http://www.ard-text.de/"
  ]
}
}
}
```

and i try to access the following data in JQuery:

```
 "highlighting": {
    "de.ard-text.www:http/": {
      "title_de": [
        "ARD Text - Der Teletext im Ersten"
      ],
      "content_de": [
        "ARD Text - Der Teletext im Ersten Nutzen Sie bitte zur bestmöglichen Audio-Ausgabe die"
      ],
      "url_de": [
        "http://www.ard-text.de/"
      ]
    }
  }
```

fields:

```
highlighting.title_de
highlighting.content_de
highlighting.url_de
```

My problem is that the ID of the highlighting fields is variable based on the initial ID.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/B5HGa/)

suppose 
`var data = {}` has all json

now

```
var h = data.highlighting ;

$.each(h, function(key, value){
    var a = value ;
    alert(a.title_de);
    alert(a.content_de);
    alert(a.url_de);

});
```

Comment: dont we need to take the ID ("id": "de.ard-text.www:http/") from response.docs firsthand to identify the id's under highlighting? I tried your example but no luck yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming `de.ard-text.www:http/` to something like `data` accessing the fields like `highlighting.data.title_de`

Comment: I can't change th id's unfortunately